# Constructor of classes with templates

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to make a class for OpenGL uniform vars and I thought of using templates for this class.

It looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
class UniformVar {
public:
    UniformVar() = delete;
};
```

The class only is constructible for some typenames, like `floats`.

So the declaration for floats looks like this:

```
template<>
class UniformVar<float> {
public:
    UniformVar(Shader *shader, std::string varName);

    float getVar();
    void setVar(float var);

private:
    Shader *shader;
    std::string varName;
};
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how to define the constructor in the cpp file. It looks like this:

```
template<>
UniformVar::UniformVar(Shader *shader, std::string varName) {

}

float UniformVar::getVar() {

}

void UniformVar::setVar(float var) {

}
```

In the second line of this code I get the compiler error `'UniformVar' is not a class, namespace, or enumeration`.

I tried to do something like this:

```
UniformVar::UniformVar<float>(Shader *shader, std::string varName) {
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try `UniformVar<float>::UniformVar( ... )`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thanks, that worked! Can you write this as answer so that I can close the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to explicitly define a templated constructor (or a class method of any kind) outside of the template definition, generally is:

> template-name::method( parameters )

So, in your case, with the method being the template's constructor, it would be:

```
UniformVar<float>::UniformVar(Shader *shader, std::string varName)
```